# Why did Snape need Filch's help to cure his leg?

Tags: harry-potter, severus-snape, continuity

When Snape gets his leg bitten by Fluffy, he goes to Filch for help.

> Snape and Filch were inside, alone.  Snape was  holding  his robes above his knees. One of his legs  was bloody and mangled. Filch was handing Snape bandages.
>   <sub>(*Harry Potter and the Philosopher's Stone - Chapter 11*)</sub>

Why would Snape need this? We know that Snape is highly skilled in curing magical wounds, as can be seen regarding Dumbledore's arm.

> Had it not been for Professor Snape’s timely action when I returned to Hogwarts, desperately  injured, I might not have  lived to  tell the tale.
>   <sub>(*Harry Potter and the Half-Blood Prince - Chapter 23*)</sub>

Also, of all people to go to, why go to Filch? Filch is a squib.

> “He did it, he did it!”  Filch spat,  his pouchy face  purpling. “You saw what he wrote on the wall!  He found — in my office — he knows I’m a — I’m a —” Filch’s face worked horribly. “He knows I’m a  Squib!” he  finished.
>   <sub>(*Harry Potter and the Chamber of Secrets - Chapter 9*)</sub>

### Why did Snape need Filch's help to cure his leg?

Comment: I'm not interely sure, but isn't that Half Blood Prince quote from Dumbledore? And wasn't it referring to an injury caused by dark magic? Because if so, and I correctly recall the books, the difference is that Snape is gifted with things related to dark magic (counters included). Not dog bites

Comment: @Oak - Fluffy wasn't exactly an ordinary dog.

Comment: Maybe Filch is the first person he ran into? He could count on Filch keeping quiet on the matter or being to dumb to ask any hard questions? Even though Snape helped setup the protection, was he supposed to be in that room at that specific time?

Comment: @ibid It still is a dog... or well, three dogs. Regardless it's a physical ailment, not magical :P

Comment: Filch helped Snape to cure his leg "the day before Harry's first Quidditch match" (the Trio sees Snape, Snape confiscates Quiddtich through the Ages, Harry sees Filch and Snape alone) and, as the beginning of the chapter states, in November (1992).Since we know that the Quidditch match took place on Saturday, the episode occured on November,6th 1992(first Friday on November 1992),a week later than Halloween, when Snape was bitten. Therefore, Filch wasn't the first person Snape run into.

Comment: Filch will definitely keep quiet. When Snape slowed the curse on Dumbledore he used his skills against dark magic and with potions to help Dumbledore. When he healed his leg he couldn't simply magic it fixed as he doesn't know much healing magic. The easiest way was just to bandage it and let it heal on its own. Fiilch was reliable and could help bandage the leg.

Comment: @Oak - If it was a physical ailment then it should have been a lot easier curable. *broadly speaking, wizards would have the power to correct or override 'mundane' nature, but not 'magical' nature* ([Pottermore](https://www.pottermore.com/writing-by-jk-rowling/illness-and-disability))

Comment: @A.Darwin One correction: Harry's first year at Hogwarts was 1991, not 1992. Halloween (October 31st) was a Thursday, so Harry would have seen Snape and Filch the next day (Friday). Assuming, of course, that JKR - math-challenged as she is - even consulted an actual calendar when writing the book. The 1st of September appears to be a Sunday every single year Harry attended Hogwarts.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Snape is highly [skilled](http://beta.hp-lexicon.org/character/snape-family/severus-snape/) in healing magic. But in this case, as he took help from Filch (a squib, with [zero](http://beta.hp-lexicon.org/character/argus-filch/) experience in healing magic) instead of Madam Pomfrey, who does maintain confidentiality if required like in the case of Ron when he shows up with a dragon bite in Philosophers stone implies that they may be trying to heal the bite-wound in non magical ways.

At Hogwarts who is better option than a squib (Filch) for Snape to treat a wound in a non magical way (Rabies Therapy, maybe because its rare in European dogs but as Fluffy's origin are unknown to Snape, he gave it a try. Prevention is better than cure)

Also there will not be many magical heals for Dog-bites because diseases caused by dogs are very rare in Britain or in Europe.

**Update:** As pointed by ibid, JKR mentioned in Pottermore that Wizards are [sort of](https://www.pottermore.com/writing-by-jk-rowling/illness-and-disability) immune to Muggle diseases.

**Edit 1:** Snape would have just used [Ferula](http://beta.hp-lexicon.org/spell/ferula/) spell to tie bandages in place but the presence of Filch strongly suggests that he was being helped in a non magical way.

> He hurried over to Ron, bent down, tapped Ron’s leg with his wand and muttered, ‘Ferula.’ Bandages spun up Ron’s leg, strapping it tightly to a splint. Lupin helped him to his feet; Ron put his weight gingerly on the leg and didn’t wince.
>
> ‘That’s better,’ he said. ‘Thanks.’
>
> <sub>*Harry Potter and The Prisoner of Azkaban - Chapter 19*</sub>

**Edit 2:** As Mike.C.Ford pointed, Fluffy as well as other creatures in wizarding world are [assumed](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/72498/why-was-fluffy-a-big-deal-when-there-was-killing-curse-in-existence) to be resistant to Killing Curse. It is also possible that these creatures attacks or bites may not be treated by magical healing. That may be the reason why Snape went to Filch for his bite-wound.

> Giants are a legitimate threat when combating wizards, however if you could simply kill them with Avada Kedavra, they are actually just giant muggles and in essence worthless.

Comment: *broadly speaking, wizards would have the power to correct or override 'mundane' nature, but not 'magical' nature* ([Pottermore](https://www.pottermore.com/writing-by-jk-rowling/illness-and-disability))

Comment: Thanks, I never came across that article on pottermore. This answer had been puched in face though.

Comment: Because I absolutely love self-promoting my own answers, I will point out that you can find a list of all of JKR's random Harry Potter stuff over [here](http://scifi.stackexchange.com/a/114611/55866).

Comment: I always thought he went to Filch because he didn't want to alert other people with why he tried to pass Fluffy. He was suspecting from Quirrell and following him when he got hurt. Dumbledore knew it, of course, but there was no reason to cause panic by revealing he got bitten by the giant dog. People would get suspicious. So he kept it quite by going to Filch. But Harry saw it all, weirdly.

Comment: Like mentioned,Madam Pomfrey does hold secrets...

Comment: Well considering that it's likely that Fluffy was [resistant to magic](http://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/72498/why-was-fluffy-a-big-deal-when-there-was-killing-curse-in-existence), it's entirely possible that his bites were resistant to magical forms of healing, which would make this theory much more plausible.

Comment: Out of universe, it is because Filch is perceived as an antagonist at this point in the story. His presence, and Snape's not going to Madam Pomfrey, is supposed to make the reader suspect Snape of being the thief and an ally of Voldemort. He didn't magically cure himself because there was no way Harry could have witnessed that. I assume you were asking about the reason in-universe, but I think the out-of-universe factor is strong here.

Comment: Accepted because I am legally bound to accept any answer with links to hp-lexicon's secret new site. :) And because it's a pretty good answer.

Comment: There is literally nothing in the books to suggest that Fluffy had Rabies or that Snape had anything more than a cut up leg.